# Changing the order of limits of sums dependent on the variables in limit operators

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given following conditions:

1. $$\forall_{i,j\in\Bbb N} \ a_{i,j}\in \Bbb N_0,$$
2. $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a_{i,j}}{nm}=1,$$

can the order of limit operators  be exchanged? That is, is it true that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a_{i,j}}{nm}=\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a_{i,j}}{nm} \ ?$$

Also, does the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{i,j}}{n} $ exist for every $j \in \Bbb N $?

Comment: What is $\mathbb N_0?$

Comment: In general, if $a_{ij}\geq 0$ then the two limits can be exchanged.

Comment: @zhw. By $\Bbb N_0$ I meant the set of natural numbers including $0$, while by $\Bbb N$ the set of natural numbers without $0$.

Comment: @Rigel No, even if both limits exist they need not be the same. You may have been thinking of integrals, but here we divide by the number of terms in the sum, that changes things. If for example $a_{ij} = 0$ if $i > j$ and $a_{ij} = 1$ for $i \leqslant j$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^m \frac{a_{ij}}{nm} = 1 \neq 0 = \lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^m \frac{a_{ij}}{nm}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have overlooked the question.